# Objective C: Catch event when an audio is finish to play

Tags: iphone, objective-c, audiotoolbox

i'm new in Objective C, i'm developing an app that play sound on touch event of an uibutton.
When i touch the button, it change is image and audio starts to playing. When audio is finish to play, i want to put the original image of uibutton. How can i do that? How can i catch the event of  the audio that is finish? 
i'm using that code:

```
- (SystemSoundID) createSoundID: (NSString*)name
{
    NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@/%@",
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath], name];              
    NSURL* filePath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: path isDirectory: NO];
    SystemSoundID soundID;
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef)filePath, &soundID);
    return soundID;
}
```

In

```
viewDidLoad
```

i call

```
freq = [self createSoundID: @"freq.wav"];
```

and in function that is called on button's touch i use:

```
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(freq);
```

How can i do? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if it's possible with the AudioService API but you can use `AVAudioPlayer` instead and assign a delegate that implements the `AVAudioPlayerDelegate` protocol and does something when `audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:successfully:` is called.

Remember to add the `AVFoundation` framework.

Example:

In your interface definition:

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
```

...

```
@inteface SomeViewController : UIViewController <AVAudioPlayerDelegate>
```

...

```
@propety(nonatomic, retain) AVAudioPlayer *player;
```

In your implementation:

```
@synthesize player;
```

...

```
// in some viewDidLoad or init method
self.player = [[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundUrl error:NULL] autorelease];
self.player.delegate = self;
```

...

```
- (void)pressButton:(id)sender {
  // set play image
  [self.player stop];
  self.player.currentTime = 0;
  [self.player play];
}
```

...

```
- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag {
   // set finish image
}
```

...

```
# in some dealloc or viewDidUnload method
self.player = nil;
```

Comment: There is a problem, when i touch button, it waits a second or two to play and change image :/

Comment: Do you create the `AVAudioPlayer` each time you play the sound? you can also try to call `prepareToPlay` after create to preload the sound data. You should probably try to reuse the same `AVAudioPlayer` instance each time.

Comment: You added `[self.player prepareToPlay];` after `AVAudioPlayer` alloc/init? didn't make any difference?

Comment: Weird as `AVAudioPlayer` should play asynchronously. Maybe add some logging with time and see what method call that takes time?

Comment: Is this in the simulator or on a real device? i know that `AVAudioPlayer` is quite slow in the simulator some times.

Comment: Sorry, i was saying of your back post, not this! :) it works very good! :) but now i have another problem, sorry: my button is a white square with a figure inside. when i click the background of button change the color in gray in the millisec it change image, what can i do to resolve it? :) thanks you very much!

Comment: You should probably open another question about that. Can't really understand the question, you don't want the button to grey for a little while or the image changes to slow?

Comment: scuse me, but my only good program language is java, i'm new in objective c. so i make another question for the button's color. My problem still is that image changes slowly only on the first touch, in the others work more fast..

Comment: Ok good. Maybe the problem with the image is that you don't preload the image? it could probably take some time the first time for  `[UIImage imageNamed:...]` to load the image, on the second call the image is probably cached. So call `[UIImage imageNamed:...]` in some init or load method and keep a reference to it.

Comment: done! So.. i load image in viewDidLoad :                                        - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        imageOpen = [UIImage imageNamed:@"aperto.jpg"];
        imageClosed = [UIImage imageNamed:@"chiuso.jpg"];                 but my problem still exists.. when button is clicked it runs : - (IBAction)launchDialog
{
    [bottone setImage:imageClosed forState: UIControlStateNormal];
    if(self.player.playing==TRUE){
      [self.player stop]; 
    }
    
    self.player.currentTime = 0;
    [self.player play];
}

Comment: So the problem is that after you click the button and launchDialog is called it takes some time until the button is changed to the imageClosed image?

Comment: sorry, i forgot to tell you before, that i ask another question about the other problem, the color of image background.. Using this: [bottone setImage: imageOpen forState: UIControlStateNormal];
    [bottone setImage: imageOpen forState: UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [bottone setImage: imageOpen forState: UIControlStateDisabled];
    [bottone setImage: imageOpen forState: UIControlStateSelected]; All the problem are solved! :) sorry and still thanks you :)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with the AudioService API, you want to use `AudioServicesAddSystemSoundCompletion`.